# This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to fix the android studio problem? (I use the Mac OS. Android Studio Version 3.1.2)

[image]

"infer Layout" Can not fix the problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put in your button this code

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Comment: It's basics of ConstraintLayout , default it's not added. I recommended you to read about this [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)